# issue about writing a controller action test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

My Sessions Controller

```
def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    person=Person.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth.provider,auth.uid) || Person.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = person.id
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to signin_path , alert: "Authentication failed, please try again." 
  end
```

I wrote a test for testing failure action in sessions_controller_test.rb

```
 it "failure should redirect to signin_path" do
     get :failure
     assert_redirected_to :action => 'new'   
     assert_response :redirect 
 end
```

But simplecov code coverage tool doesn't accept this test as successfull. Simplecov shows this failure action as missing test.
How can I write a controller test for **failure** action. Does noone give any ideas about this?
Below image is coverage report's screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try by specifying the controller name (**sessions** hopefully) in **assert_redirect_to** statement like below.

```
assert_redirected_to :action => "new", :controller => "sessions"
```

Comment: It didn't work. In fact, test I wrote is working. But in coverage report, it seems as missing.